VerificationTest leaks message?
It seems that in certain cases VerificationTest will leak the messages generated when testing.
For example,
VerificationTest[
    Clear[x];
    x=x+1,
    TerminatedEvaluation["RecursionLimit"],
    {$RecursionLimit::reclim}
]

VerificationTest[
    Permute[{a,b},Cycles@{{1,2,3}}],
    Permute[{a,b},Cycles@{{1,2,3}}],
    {Permute::lowlen}
]


This is quite annoying when there are many tests.
Is this a bug?
How to fix this? Quiet does not work since it suppresses all the specified messages during testing, which leads to test failures.

I agree this is annoying, but when I reported it I was told it is as designed. So I adapted the way I write my tests so that re-evaluation of the expected output does not issue a message.  For your second example I would write it in one of these forms:
VerificationTest[Head @ Permute[{a, b}, Cycles @ {{1, 2, 3}}],
  Permute,
  {Permute::lowlen}
]

VerificationTest[Permute[{a, b}, Cycles @ {{1, 2, 3}}],
  HoldPattern[Permute[{a, b}, Cycles @ {{1, 2, 3}}]],
  {Permute::lowlen}, SameTest -> MatchQ
]



Very useful answer! If I understand correctly, does it means that the expected output will be evaluated when testing?

@Lacia - yes indeed.  It's not how I would expect it to work either but you can see that with VerificationTest[1 + 1, 3 - 1]
